# React navigation close drawer on click bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have my `react navigation` setup as below. The drawer can be closed when press outside of the drawer component. (But not when i click on the `bottom navigator tabs part`).
How could i close the drawer when i click on the bottom navigations?

```
const HomeFilterDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        header: null,
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentComponent: DrawerComponent,
    drawerPosition: 'right',
  },
);

const HomeScreenStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeFilterDrawer,
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
        header: null,
      }),
    },
    Search: {
      ...
    },
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreenStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home,
        tabBarIcon: tabInfo => {
          return (
            <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={25} />
          );
        },
        tabBarOnPress: ({navigation}) => {
          navigation.popToTop();
          navigation.navigate(navigation.state.routeName);
        },
      },
    },
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to close the drawer using `DrawerActions`?

```js
import { DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/routers';
// ...

// in tabbaronPress call the following
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
```